# Compute the expected number of records by time n

Tags: probability-theory

This is a problem of my homework.
An asset price is modeled by using a sequence of independent and identically distributed continuous random variables $X_1,X_2,...$, with common density function $f(x)$. We say that a record price occurs at time $n$ if $Xn >
\max(X_1,X_2,...,X_{n-1})$.
Compute $P[a\ record\ price\ occurs\ at\ time\ n]$.
Next, consider the variable $Y_i$ defined as:
$Y_i = 1$ if a record occurs at time $i$.
$Y_i = 0$ otherwise.
Give the expected number of records by time n.

I already know the probability of a record price occurs at time $n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$. And let $Z_n$ be the number of records by time n. Then $Z_n = Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 +...+ Y_n$. Then the expected value of $Z_n$ should be $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 +...+ 1/n$. But in my homework, my professor suggested that "do not attempt to calculate the sum". Is calculating the sum here wrong? Or there is a better way to do the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have said correctly that the expected value of $Z_n$ is the $n^{th}$ [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).  You can't sum the series to infinity because it diverges, but for finite $n$ it is close to $\log n + \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) constant, about $0.577$

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks!