# Expectation of number of assignments

Tags: probability, expected-value

I went to an interview and there was a question that I couldn't solve, I am not $100$% sure about the exact wording, but I think was something like this:

> Given $n$ different random numbers $\{a_1, a_2,...,a_n\}$, we want to find the maximum of these numbers. First let $m=a_1$. Then, we compare $m$ to $a_2$, if $m>a_2$, reassign $m$ to be $a_2$, but if $m<a_2$, then $m$ value doesn't change. With the same method, compare $m$ to the rest of the numbers. After we're done comparing all the numbers, $m$ would be the maximum value.
>
> What is the average number of assignments of $m$ to find the maximum of the list?"

P.S - I think that setting $m=a_1$ also counts as one assignment.

Comment: It's $\log n$ (the natural logarothm of $n$). This is also known as the expected number of records. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929895/compute-the-expected-number-of-records-by-time-n and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031032/expected-number-of-record-highs-in-an-iid-sequence-of-discrete-uniform-random-va

Comment: Have you had a look at those links, S.B.?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much Gerry!

Comment: Perhaps, then, you would like to write up & post an answer to your question, based on what you've learned from those links. Or maybe it would make sense to close your question as a duplicate of one of the others.

Comment: So, whaddya think?

Comment: Yeah just close it it's fine.